# Using a Dynamic Array in a class is giving an error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a dynamic array in a class but I'm getting "a non static member must be relative to a specific object" error. Here's the code.

```
class Calendar
{
    private:
        static int holidayCount;
        int * holidayDates = new int[10];

    public:
        static void addHolidayCount() 
        {
            holidayCount++;
        }

        static int getHolidayCount()
        {
            return holidayCount;
        }

        static void addHolidayDate(int day, int month, int year)
        {
            holidayDates[0] = 1;
        }
};
```

If I use this same type of setup within my main function I don't get any errors. For example:

```
int * holidayDates = new int[10];
holidayDates[0] = 1;
```

I'm guessing I have some kind of syntax error here but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Static member cannot access non-static member

Comment: You can't use non static fields (I mean `holidayDates `) in static method (`addHolidayDate`)

Comment: I see. I should have realized that. And in there lies the dangers of copying and pasting. Thanks.

Comment: Since you usw c++, avoid the usage of 'new'. The size of your array is fixed. This means you can usw a 'std::array'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `holidayDates` member variable is non-static, so there is a separate `holidayDates` pointer (and array) for each Calendar object that you create.

Your `addHolidayDate()` method, on the other hand, is marked static, so it runs outside of the context of any particular `Calendar` object.

That means that if you try to access `holidayDates` from within `addHolidayDate()`, the compiler has no way to tell which `holidayDates` pointer you meant to use; hence the error message.

The solution is either to make `holidayDates` static as well, or make `addHolidayDate()` non-static.

Answer (score 0):

holidayDates is not a static member, you cannot directly access it in a static function.

Answer (score 0):

`static` member variables as well as functions are independent of all instances of the class. They don't need an instance of the class to be used.

Non-`static` member variables as well as functions can only be used with an instance of the class.

The problem in your code is in the function `addHolidayDate`. It is defined as a `static` member function. Hence, it is not associated with any instance. The member variable `holidayDates`, on the other hand, is a non-`static` member variable. It can be used only with an instance of the class.

I suggesting making `addHolidayDate` a non-`static` member function.

```
// Don't use static
void addHolidayDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
   holidayDates[0] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access non static fields in static methods. So remove `static` for `addHolidayDate`

```
class Calendar {
private:
    static int holidayCount;
    int * holidayDates = new int[10];

public:
    void addHolidayCount()
    {
        holidayCount++;
    }

    int getHolidayCount()
    {
        return holidayCount;
    }

    void addHolidayDate(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        holidayDates[0] = 1;
    }
};
```

Here is example how to use this class:

```
int main()
{
    Calendar* c = new Calendar();
    c->addHolidayDate(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```